# How to define dynamically / override the _default_ mapping in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Use case :

1. The index/indices will be built dynamically from a template, so that
   it will pick some custom settings (number of shards/replicas/ etc).
2. Generate dynamically the types and their mappings, enabling for them all the timestamp
   & ttl fields. Also define the same parent type for all types, except
   the parent type itself (I know its name).

   ```
   {
      "template": "*",

      "settings": {
         ...................
      },

      "mappings": {

         "_default_": {
            "_parent": {
               "type": "ParentType"
            },
            "_timestamp": {
               "enabled": true,
               "store": true
            },
            "_ttl": {
               "enabled": true
            }
         }

      }
   }
   ```

How could I disable the _parent field for the ParentType type itself ?

Answer (score 1):

After a little big of digging on the docs, I found out that you can override `__default__` mappings using this work around.

```
{
   "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
         "_parent": {
             "type": "my_parent_type" # 1
         }
      },
      "my_parent_type": {
          "_parent": {
              "type": "_dummy" # 2
          }
      }
   }
}
```

**1)** This mapping configuration will be inherited by all your types including `my_parent_type`type. Step 2 explains how to override your parent type `_parent` meta-field.

**2)** I found here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/default-mapping.html that you can override any of the mappings from `__default__` when you provide a specific mapping for the type in question.

In this case we are assigning the `_parent` mapping of `my_parent_type` to a `_dummy` parent type that does not have to exists in your index.

**Note**: ElasticSearch 2.x documentation states:

> The `_parent.type` setting can only point to a type that doesn’t exist yet. This means that a type cannot become a parent type after it is has been created.

For this reason, you have to make sure you index **first**, a document that is not `my_parent_type` type, otherwise you'll get an at indexing time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But when index parent document you still require `?parent=`, if not you will get error. Right now I am using a dummy value `nil` for `_parent` field, I don't know if it bad for performent or not.And sometime misleading too . Is there a way remove it ?